# How can I create a tag in Gitlab CI using Tags API?

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I'm trying to create a tag from a job using Tags API. Can I do it using job token or a private token is necessary? When I try creating a tag using `JOB_TOKEN` I get `Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"404 Project Not Found"}` as a response.

```
$tagName = [Uri]::EscapeDataString($env:FULL_PRODUCT_VERSION)
$ref = [Uri]::EscapeDataString($env:CI_COMMIT_SHA)

$createTagApiEndpoint = "$env:CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$env:CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/tags?tag_name=$tagName&ref=$ref"
$headers = @{"JOB-TOKEN" = $env:CI_JOB_TOKEN}

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Method POST -Uri $createTagApiEndpoint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to use the `JOB_TOKEN` if the `ci_job_token_scope` feature is enabled, as described in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html):

```rb
Feature.enable(:ci_job_token_scope)
```

It is disabled by default.